# Does a resistor make also a higher physical resistence to el. current along with more chemical resistence than does a conductor?

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-current, electrical-resistance

Does a resistor make also a higher physical resistence to electric current along with more chemical resistence than does a conductor? Asking so because of the fact that a resistor is always the hottest part of the circuit. In other words... should the resistor get more heat even it has the same crossection area as a conductor? Also are free electrons the cause of metals being highly efficient thermal conductors?

Comment: I am puzzled by the phrase “more chemical resistance” in your first sentence. What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

> Does a resistor make also a higher physical resistence to electric current  ... than does a conductor?

Yes. That's why we call it a resistor. There is no principle difference between a "conductor" and a "resistor". They both have resistance (ignoring superconductors). The main difference is that conductors are engineered to have as small a resistance as possible and resistors are designed to have a specific target resistance.

> should the resistor get more heat even it has the same crossection area as a conductor?

Yes. Heat is energy that is dissipated when the electrons collide with resistive material. The amount of thermal power that is $R\cdot I^2$, i.e. it's the resistance  multiplied with the squire of the current. The higher the resistance the more heat gets generated (for the same current). Conductors can get quite hot as well: you just need to pump enough current through them.

Answer (score 0):

In the classical model, a resistor has a lower density of free electrons.  This means that for a given current, the flow rate, electric field, and and voltage gradient must be larger.  Each free electron has a greater acceleration, gains more speed, and loses more energy with each collision with an atom.